# rails javascript not responding when in mailer.js file but does when in page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

for some reason when I embed a javascript in the html document this code works here's the process_orders.html.erb code

```
<script>
function myFunction(val) {
if (val.length == 2) {
document.getElementById('search_button').focus();
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");}    
}
</script>

<%= form_tag(process_orders_mailers_path, :method => "get") do %>
<%= text_field_tag :id, nil, autofocus: true, onkeyup:"myFunction(this.value)" %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil, :id => 'search_button' %>
<% end %>
```

however when I put this code in an external js file it does work. Here is the code in the file mailers.js. That is the ONLY code that is in the mailers.js file.
The mailers.js is the same name of the controller that the form above belongs to:

```
function myFunction(val) {
if (val.length == 2) {
document.getElementById('search_button').focus();
alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");}
```

}

essentially what I am trying to do is after 2 characters get entered in the text field the alert is displayed. Again, it works fine when all the code is in the html file.... thanks for the help

Comment: Did you check the browser console to see if it triggers an error? Did you check in the browser console, in the sources tab to see if `mailer.js` is being required?

Comment: When you say "however when I put this code in an external js file it does work" do you mean "however when I put this code in an external js file it **does not** work"?  Please edit your question and show how you are including the external js file.

Comment: Yes, I meant "does not work". When I remove the script tag from the html file and check the console I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined" error. Does that help... and I do have the script included in the  javascripts folder, and the file name is mailers.js